# What is the hierarchy of the units that audio devices consist of on PipeWire?

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm trying to understand the audio device hierarchy for PipeWire. Looking through the output of `pw-dump` has given me a good idea, but I still find it very difficult to grasp the whole picture.

My understanding is, that the structure is probably close to this:

```
Devices: [{
    Profiles: [{
        Nodes: [{ // Sinks and Sources
            Formats: [...]
            Ports: [...] // in or out
            Routes: [...]
        }],
    }]
}]
```

So, the biggest unit is a device. (e.g. a sound card)

- A device can have one or more profiles. (e.g. Analog Stereo Duplex, Analog Stereo Input, Analog Stereo Output, Pro Audio, ...)

  - A profile can have one or more nodes.

    - A node can be a sink (output) or a source (input).
    - A node can have one or more formats (e.g. s32le @ 48kHz).
    - A node can have one or more routes (e.g. Speaker/Headphones or Internal Mic/Headset Mic)
    - A node can have one or more ports

      - A port can be an input-port (e.g. mic right) or an output-port (speaker left)

But that can't be quite right. When I look at a device it seems like the routes are defined on the device-level, suggesting that routes are profile-independent and also node-independent. But then it gets even more complicated because for each route there is an array of profiles. And then there is also an array of devices on the route level.

Is there maybe a diagram that explains the structure better? I find it very difficult to reverse-engineer the output of `pw-dump` in order to get this right.